# Can't connect to home network from school

Tags: networking, ssh

So, I set up an SSH connection to a computer on my home network. The port-forward directs from port 8001 to 22 on the computer. The connection works fine externally, but in my schools public network it doesn't seem to be able to connect to my home network. I can use a VPN and it works fine, but free options are mostly unstable and it's always a hassle setting the connection up.

So are there any common tricks to solve this?

Comment: Your school's network (firewall) is most likely blocking the connection on port 8001. If a VPN isn't an option you could try to create an SSH tunnel over some open port (maybe HTTPS 443).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are behind a firewall that protects your schools network, which probably blocks communication on "unusual" ports, like 8001.

You might want to try to use ports that are more likely to be open from the network. Ports like 80 or 443 will probably work in this regard.

Comment: Oh, stupid me! Ofcourse I don't go to school on saturday, but I have now changed the port, and I'll be able to verify on monday.

Comment: That kind of stuff happens :D